# What is the correct way to use Chef from Ruby (Rails)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I'm very new with Chef, maybe I search wrong but Google show a lot of quick starts and deployment options, but mostly on how to deploy an app from dev's console. What I need is to perform recipes from the Rails app.

I have a stack which includes Rails+Resque as a master and Chef as a slave. Chef is added as a gem `chef`, the `chef/shef/ext` used inside the app to run queries.

It should do several things, like create ssh users (which works) and deploy new app stacks (which don't).

As the `chef` gem doesn't have a lot of docs and `ext` doesn't feel like user (or dev) oriented too, I think there should be some other way to work with Chef server (knife?), or some kind of documentation on gem I definitely miss to work effitiantly with this.

Comment: Best thing to do is following the tutorials on opscode http://www.opscode.com/ and initially use hosted chef. In my experience this is the best way to learn chef. Once you understand how opscode prefer the technology to be use you'll be in a better position to decide whether you can use your own chef server or chef-solo.

Comment: It depends on whether you're executing chef recipes on the host that runs your Rails app or any remote machines. I would suggest invoking knife by ruby code so that your Rails app plays the role of chef workstation. Please refer to this question for reference: [invoking knife in a ruby class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826003/invoking-knife-in-a-ruby-class)

Comment: I already has a stack with Chef on dedicated server, and don't want to mess this for now (as it probably would kill the code which works fine in the moment). @shawnzhu, thank you, seems this is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got stuck on something similar and ended up using the [ridley gem](http://github.com/RiotGames/ridley):

[As per this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977607/using-knife-from-rails-application).

Comment: I've finished with a knife usage, but the suggested gem looks cool. Thank you.